# How to set getLine to only receive strings that can be converted to numbers?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

```
main = do 
putStrLn "Hello,Name please?"
first <- getLine
second <- getLine
third <- getLine
if (second == "divide") then putStrLn (show (read first ::Double )/ (read third :: Double))
    else putStrLn "Cannot do"
```

So i want a number in first and third variables,and the second variable will be given the work `divide` and the if statement will begin and convert the `String` in first to a `Double`.But i think the issue is that the variable `First` is expecting a String like "one" that cannot be converted to a Double.How to fix this to allow getLine to only receive Strings that can be changed in numbers

Comment: What should happen if the user types a random string, instead?

Comment: didn't think about that,throw an error maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick idea that could help you:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char

getNum :: (Num a, Read a) => IO (Maybe a)
getNum = do
  (x, xs) <- break (not . isDigit ) <$> getLine
  case xs of
    [] -> return $ Just $ read x
    _ -> return Nothing

main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- getNum :: IO (Maybe Double)
  case x of
    Nothing -> do
      putStrLn "Not a number, try again"
      main
    Just x' ->
      putStrLn $ "Your number: " ++ show x'
  return ()
```

You cannot "make" getLine accept only numbers, you make a function that does. You can even modify this function to accept only the first set of numbers before a non-digit (right now it returns `Nothing` if any non-digit is in the string).

**Update**

Here's a program that asks for two numbers and an operation, doing some value checking:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Char
import Data.Maybe

getNum :: (Num a, Read a) => IO (Maybe a)
getNum = do
  (x, xs) <- break (not . isDigit ) <$> getLine
  case xs of
    [] -> return $ Just $ read x
    _ -> return Nothing

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStr "First: "
  x <- getNum :: IO (Maybe Double)

  putStr "Operation: "
  op <- getLine

  putStr "Second: "
  y <- getNum :: IO (Maybe Double)

  if isJust x && isJust y then do
    let
      x' = fromJust x
      y' = fromJust y
    putStr "Result: "
    case op of
      "divide" -> putStrLn $ show $ x' / y'
      "sum" -> putStrLn $ show $ x' + y'
      _ -> putStrLn "No operation"
  else
    putStrLn "Invalid numbers"

  return ()
```

Comment: Instead of defining your own validator, why not use `readMaybe` from `Text.Read`? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Yeah, it is absolutely valid to go that way (or even better).